# Decoding a base64 encryption on other device

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I am using python build in library to encode a md5 digest using base 64. Library i am using is :

```
      from hashlib import md5
```

My code to encode the "email" variable:

```
     apitoken = md5(email).digest().encode('base64')[:-1]
```

Now the problem is this "apitoken" is being sent to other device who need to decode the base64 it to get email md5.

What key should I send to them? Where is this salt value?

Comment: Base-64 isn't encryption, it's an encoding. You just decode it with `.decode('base64')`.

Comment: yup i can decode it using .decode but what about decoding it in other device let's say android. I it possible or any other method?

Comment: Sure, but why are you sending the data as base-64 in the first place?

Comment: Client says so haha...I need to send encrypted data I guess this is not the way. So how do I encrypt it with a key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your requirement is to send encrypted data then you should not use a one-way hashing algorithm like MD5 (which is a weak algorithm, in any case). I would recommend using well known symmetric/asymmetric algorithms like AES say from the [Python Cryptography Toolkit (pycrypto)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycrypto)

The encrypted data can be unencrypted at the client end using an appropriate client library for that algorithm. I would also recommend reading a good book on security such as Bruce Schneier's "Applied Cryptography" to understand how to build a secure system.